# Laravel. What is a token in HTTP requests?

Tags: laravel, web, backend

In Laravel documentation this middleware checks if the requests have a token with the name 'my-secret-token':

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->input('token') !== 'my-secret-token') {
        return redirect('home');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

What is this token in the HTTP requests? I looked in the HTTP RFC and tokens are mentioned but for a different purpose(Product Tokens).

Comment: This's just an example of how to add some layer of security to the middleware, don't get overwhelmed.

Comment: `$request->input()` is just the input passed througha  form or ajax/fetch queries. It could be an `<input type="text" name="token">` or an `<input type="hidden" name="token">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an example of defining a middleware to allow access to the route only when the specified `token` matches the specified value (`my-secret-token`).

The `token` can be anything that you use to authenticate the user. Here is an example:

```
// route definition
Route::get('/home', function () {
    return view('home', ['token' => YourHelper::getToken()]);
});

// in your home view
<input type="hidden" name="token" id="token" value="{{ $token }}" />

// in your middleware
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!YourHelper::validateToken($request->input('token'))) {
        return redirect('home');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: I thought "token" was part of the HTTP header, but user IGP clarified that is just a variable name coming from a form or ajax query.

Comment: @Carlitos_30 Yeah, it's just an input that the client `sends back` to the server.